# gl::DrawArrays fails when tesselation shaders attached

Tags: opengl, rust, glsl, shader, tesselation

I'm using the OpenGL SuperBible 6th edition, and learning about tessellation shaders. I get a `INVALID_OPERATION` error from `gl::DrawArrays`. This is my code:

```
extern crate libc;
extern crate glutin;
extern crate gl;

use std::io::Read;

fn main() {
    unsafe {
        let win = glutin::WindowBuilder::new()
                  .with_gl_profile(glutin::GlProfile::Core)
                  .build_strict()
                  .unwrap();

        win.make_current().unwrap();
        gl::load_with(|s| win.get_proc_address(s));

        gl::DebugMessageCallback(
            std::mem::transmute(gl_debug_message),
            std::ptr::null_mut());

        let program = build_shader_program();
        gl::UseProgram(program);

        let mut vao = std::mem::uninitialized();
        gl::GenVertexArrays(1, &mut vao);
        gl::BindVertexArray(vao);

        gl::PolygonMode(gl::FRONT_AND_BACK, gl::LINE);

        let red = [1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0];

        let mut running = true;
        while running {
            for event in win.poll_events() {
                if let glutin::Event::Closed = event {
                    running = false;
                }
            }

            win.swap_buffers().unwrap();
            gl::ClearBufferfv(gl::COLOR, 0, &red[0]);

            gl::DrawArrays(gl::TRIANGLES, 0, 3);
        }
    }
}

extern "system"
fn gl_debug_message(_source: u32, _type: u32, _id: u32, _sev: u32,
                    _len: i32, message: *const libc::c_char,
                    _param: *mut libc::c_void)
{
    unsafe {
        let s = cstring_to_string(message);
        panic!("OpenGL Debug message: {}", s);
    }
}

fn build_shader_program() -> u32 {
    let vert = load_and_compile_shader("a.vert", gl::VERTEX_SHADER);
    let tesc = load_and_compile_shader("a.tesc", gl::TESS_CONTROL_SHADER);
    let tese = load_and_compile_shader("a.tese", gl::TESS_EVALUATION_SHADER);
    let frag = load_and_compile_shader("a.frag", gl::FRAGMENT_SHADER);

    unsafe {
        let program_id = gl::CreateProgram();
        gl::AttachShader(program_id, vert);
        gl::AttachShader(program_id, tesc);
        gl::AttachShader(program_id, tese);
        gl::AttachShader(program_id, frag);
        gl::LinkProgram(program_id);

        let mut result = std::mem::uninitialized();
        gl::GetProgramiv(program_id, gl::LINK_STATUS, &mut result);
        assert_eq!(result, gl::TRUE as i32);

        program_id
    }
}

unsafe fn cstring_to_string(mut cs: *const libc::c_char) -> String {
    let mut v : Vec<u8> = Vec::new();
    while *cs != 0 {
        v.push(*cs as u8);
        cs = cs.offset(1);
    }
    String::from_utf8(v).expect("c-string not utf8")
}

fn load_file_as_cstring(path: &str) -> std::ffi::CString {
    let mut contents = Vec::new();
    let mut file = std::fs::File::open(path).unwrap();
    file.read_to_end(&mut contents).unwrap();
    std::ffi::CString::new(contents).unwrap()
}

fn load_and_compile_shader(path: &str, shader_type: u32) -> u32 {
    let contents = load_file_as_cstring(path);
    unsafe {
        let shader_id = gl::CreateShader(shader_type);

        let source_ptr = contents.as_ptr();
        gl::ShaderSource(shader_id, 1, &source_ptr, std::ptr::null());
        gl::CompileShader(shader_id);

        let mut result = std::mem::uninitialized();
        gl::GetShaderiv(shader_id, gl::COMPILE_STATUS, &mut result);
        assert_eq!(result, gl::TRUE as i32);

        shader_id
    }
}
```

Running this program causes a debug message:

```
OpenGL Debug message: glDrawArrays has generated an error (GL_INVALID_OPERATION)
```

I've omitted the shaders (a vertex shader, a fragment shader, a tessellation control shader and a tessellation evaluation shader), but I can show them if that is necessary. They are very basic, I just didn't want to clutter the question. In fact they are the ones in [this example program](https://github.com/openglsuperbible/sb6code/blob/master/src/tessellatedtri/tessellatedtri.cpp) from the sb6 git repository. They compile and link with no errors.

If I remove the calls to `gl::AttachShader` for both tessellation shaders, there are no errors, and a simple wireframe triangle is drawn. With the tessellation shaders, it is supposed to draw the same triangle, just cut up into smaller triangles.

I've looked the documentation for `glDrawArrays` [on this site](https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/), and my code doesn't seem to be doing any of the things that can cause an `INVALID_OPERATION` error, afaict.

Comment: Only `GL_PATCH` primitives may be submitted to a shader program that has a tessellation shader, but you are submitting `GL_TRIANGLES`.

Answer (score 1):

A tessellation shader does not render primitives, but patches. The primitives are created during the tessellation. See [Tessellation](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Tessellation).

You must use the [Primitive](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Primitive) type `gl::PATCHES` instead of `gl::TRIANGLES`. In addition, you have to specify the size of a single patch by setting the parameter `gl::PATCH VERTICES` with `gl::PatchParameteri`:

<s>`gl::DrawArrays(gl::TRIANGLES, 0, 3);`</s>

```rust
gl::PatchParameteri(gl::PATCH_VERTICES, 3);
gl::DrawArrays(gl::PATCHES, 0, 3);
```